# EF commands don't work in ASP.NET Core, how to configure project.json?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm doing a project and following tutorial ASP.NET Core Fundamentals on Pluralsight. However, the instructor recorded this using ASP.NET MVC 5, so sometimes there are some differences.

I'm on the stage of configuration project.json so I can use Entity Framework, but it doesn't work. Commands are recognizable by cmd, but I have the information

> The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.0-rc2-3002702' was not found.
>     - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>         C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
>     - The following versions are installed:
>         1.0.0
>     - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.0-rc2-3002702'.

I have installed this version of framework, and I have warning that Microsoft.EntityFramework.Tools and Microsoft.EntityFramework.Design expect version of Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0, but when i change it I still have same mistake.

Here is link to my project.json code: http://pastebin.com/g0TDqykY
It takes a lot of time to restore packages again and again on my PC..
Any ideas what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Basically with help of [this tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html) from Microsoft, which shows how to add New Database to the project with Entity Framework. I've created a new project, then compared my own project and changed project.json so it was the same as the one from tutorial. Also had to add constructor in my DbContext class. I hope it can be helpful if you ever have this problem.